# How to mount /dev/bus/usb on VSCode's devcontainer for docker?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, containers

I did this on my `devcontainer.json` as specified [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference):

```
"mounts": ["source=/dev/bus/usb,target=/dev/bus/usb"]
```

but I got

```
[2022-03-05T22:04:50.779Z] docker: Error response from daemon: create /dev/bus/usb: "/dev/bus/usb" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
```

It looks to me that `/dev/bus/usb` is already an absolute path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that this is a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

```json
"mounts": ["type=bind,source=/dev/bus/usb,target=/dev/bus/usb"]
```